# Hotornot - How is the previous image memorized?

Tags: php, variables, cookies, session-variables

The question might make you smile but how does [this website](http://www.hotornot.com) keep a trace of what the previous image is? I mean, the central image is probably picked at random as well as the next image but the previous image has to correspond with the one a user has just evaluated. Is this done via session variables? If so, how are ids chained and is there a limit to how much information could be stored?

P.S: Also just thought of cookies. Would be interested to hear about what strategies are possible.

Comment: What image are you talking about?

Comment: @Wesley, probably hotornot.com ?

Comment: I didn't realise it was a website, in the question it says 'this website'...so I was looking for an image on stackexchange.

Comment: @Wesley van Opdorp: Sorry I assumed that many people knew about the site and wanted to avoid publicity :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had taken a look at the sources, there's a hidden form field

`<input type="hidden" name="rating[voted_on_id]" value="17915927" id="rating_voted_on_id" class="hidden"/>`

My bet would be that this is the ID you're looking for, as the other two are also stored this way by the looks of it...

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble. So the id of the person being voted for is being passed to the PHP page. Since there can be N users viewing a page they must be differentiated somehow. If the id of the previous image is stored in the database it's probably being retrieved using a composite key formed from this id and one kept in the session. That would be one way of doing it.

Comment: @James P. There's a session ID cookie as well to differentiate the users themselves, you asked how the previous profile is stored :) . The way I see it, the form gets submitted, the current votee's score recalced & the current votee's ID output to the response as previous.

Comment: The question could have been better expressed. What I meant to ask was how the server could figure out the id of the second image before the current one (information is lost since a person left the page) when a user is anonymous. So, yes, a session variable is probably the way it's done.

Answer (score 2):

The vote would need to be stored. My guess is, the previous vote is stored in the database based on IP (or a combination of visitor information). Then on any new page load, the previous voting history is loaded and used to load a non-voted image to compare to.

There are perhaps lots of different ways, setting a cookie or adding session variables probably makes sense for the short term.

Comment: IP alone makes completely no sense. There are not that many ways to identify a user, most of them are cookie based.

Comment: A combination of IP + Unique hash and other variables might be used to save and reload/re-use.

Comment: My point was that identifying a user by values initially supplied by the user is non-sense. The session ID used for a cookie on the other hand is server supplied.

Comment: Well, it is a good practise to avoid using client-supplied information as much as possible (considered as unreliable). However the hash that Luceos is referring to could be provided through a session id. The IP could be kept for other identification purposes. See http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/how-to-get-php-session-id-code-sample-to-show-obtain-display-phpsessid-t518.html.

Comment: It's always smart to store as much info as possible and use that to create a visitor profile. You'll never know when you'll need it..